# how to fix <iframe> in a <div>?

Tags: html, iframe

Here is my html

exactly as I want

```
 <div style="display: flex;">
                <div style="border: solid; width: 20%; display: inline-block; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: center; background-color: gainsboro;">
                    <b>AAA</b>
                </div>
                <div style="border: solid; width: 60%; display: inline-block; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: center; background-color: gainsboro;">
                    <b>BBB</b>
                </div>
                <div style="border: solid; width: 20%; display: inline-block; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: center; background-color: gainsboro;">
                    <b>CCC</b>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div style="display: flex;">
                <div style="border: solid; width: 20%; display: inline-block; margin: 0; padding: 0; background-color: aqua;">
                    A1<br />
                    A2<br />
                    A3
                    
                </div>
                <div style="border: solid; width: 60%; display: inline-block; margin: 0; padding: 0; background-color: pink;">


                    <%--<iframe src="/images/sample1.pdf" style="height: 700px; width: 100%;"/>--%>
                </div>
                <div style="border: solid; width: 20%; display: inline-block; margin: 0; padding: 0; background-color: yellow;">
                    C1<br />
                    C2<br />
                    C3
                    
                </div>
            </div>
```

I want to add an iframe in the pink area (BBB)

When I do that.. the yellow area (CCC) completely gone !!

```
 <div style="display: flex;">
                <div style="border: solid; width: 20%; display: inline-block; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: center; background-color: gainsboro;">
                    <b>AAA</b>
                </div>
                <div style="border: solid; width: 60%; display: inline-block; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: center; background-color: gainsboro;">
                    <b>BBB</b>
                </div>
                <div style="border: solid; width: 20%; display: inline-block; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: center; background-color: gainsboro;">
                    <b>CCC</b>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div style="display: flex;">
                <div style="border: solid; width: 20%; display: inline-block; margin: 0; padding: 0; background-color: aqua;">
                    A1<br />
                    A2<br />
                    A3
                    
                </div>
                <div style="border: solid; width: 60%; display: inline-block; margin: 0; padding: 0; background-color: pink;">


                    <iframe src="/images/sample1.pdf" style="height: 700px; width: 100%;"/>
                </div>
                <div style="border: solid; width: 20%; display: inline-block; margin: 0; padding: 0; background-color: yellow;">
                    C1<br />
                    C2<br />
                    C3
                    



                </div>
            </div>
```

How to fix that so the iframe just set in its designated area without ruining other areas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your iframe code from this (note the backslash at the end):

```
<iframe src="/images/sample1.pdf" style="height: 700px; width: 100%;"/>
```

To this:

```
<iframe src="/images/sample1.pdf" style="height: 700px; width: 100%;">
</iframe>
```